# How to intercept requests of links without scheme?

Tags: cefsharp

I use CefSharp (86.0.241) in a WPF .NET Framework application (4.7.2; x64) to display HTML from String (not URL; see "Edit 1"). Clicks on hyperlinks should not initiate a navigation to other content, but should be handled by the application to do other things like opening system's default web browser or show information in the application's UI.

I assign an object of a custom `IRequestHandler`-class to `ChromiumWebBrowser.RequestHandler` to do the request interception. In the method implementations of `IRequestHandler` I'm able to cancel the navigation and do my stuff. This works fine for links with a scheme like `<a href="http://mynetwork/share/index.html">Click</a>`.

But if there are links without scheme (e.g. `<a href="www.google.com">Click</a>`) or relative links  (e.g. `<a href="/tmp/index.php">Click</a>`) only the `IRequestHandler.OnDocumentAvailableInMainFrame` method implementation is called by the CefSharp control. This indicates that the new content is created (navigation is done). Actually the visual content of the control disappears. In this case I'm not able to intercept the requests with my `IRequestHandler` implementation.

So what's the correct way to intercept the requests of links without scheme?

Thanks

Edit 1: To be more accurate I load the HTML from a data URI. Instead of using the `LoadHtml`-extension methods I generate them on my own (e.g. `data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,PGh0bWwvPg==` and call the instance method `ChromiumWebBrowser.Load(string url)` with it.

Edit 2: If I use a regular website like https://magpcss.org/ceforum/ the `IRequestHandler` methods are called as expected. For example the *"The team"* link in the footer is relative in the HTML code. I'm able to cancel the navigation and do something else with the URL. The `Url` property in the `IRequest request` argument of `IRequestHandler.OnBeforeBrowse` contains the absolute URL with scheme, domain etc. to the team page.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the chromium embedded framework. Cefsharp is just one of many chromium embedded framework wrappers. If you post at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewforum.php?f=18 those involved with CEF can be involved in the discussion.

Comment: How exactly Did you load the html?

Comment: Does it work if you use a regular website with relevant links? Data uri is a special case and would probably require chromium changes,  so unlikely to be fixed. If it works for regular urls then you can switch to using a ResourceHandler or a scheme handler factory.

Comment: As it works as expected for regular urls you'll have to switch from using a data uri to say a ResourceHandler. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-handling for a general overview.  Calling http://cefsharp.github.io/api/86.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_LoadHtml_2.htm with your html and a url is the easiest option.

Comment: @amaitland: You're right. Using the `LoadHtml` extension method with a URL like `zack://www.example.com` works. The method registers the default `ResourceHandler` with my new base URL and my HTML string. Then all links without scheme gets prepended by the new base URL in the arguments of `IRequestHandler` method implementations. So I'm able to handle this clicks and navigations respectively. Thank you!